# Soft question about continuos random walk

Tags: probability-distributions, soft-question

Could somebody refer to any sources, if there are any, on the study of random walks using complex numbers?I mean the kind of random walk  where a particle starts from the origin ,goes a random distance in some range in a random direction and repeats the same process again and again.The distance from origin ,for instance ,will be one quantity of interest.

Comment: Have you tried searching for "drunkard's walk"?

Comment: This is the same as a random walk in the (real) plane, right?